# mnist and cifar10 examples with TFRecord train/test file

Tags: tensorflow

I am a new user of Tensorflow. I would like to use it for training a dataset of 2M images. I did this experiment in caffe using lmdb file format.

After reading Tensorflow related posts, I realized that TFRecord is the most suitable file format to do so. Therefore, I am looking for complete CNN examples which use TFRecord data. I noticed that the image related tutorials (mnist and cifar10 in [link1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist) and [link2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image)) are provided with a different binary file format where the entire data-set is loaded at once. Therefore, I would like to know if anyone knows if these tutorials (mnist and cifar10) are available using TFRecord data (for both CPU and GPU).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to both, write and read TFRecord files. I think what is done here [reading_data.py](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py) should help you converting MNIST data into TFRecors.
For reading it back, this script does the trick: [fully_connected_reader.py](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py)
This could be done similarly with cifar10.